# How to determine an orthogonal plane that contains a line?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the plane $x+y-2z+6=0$ and want to determine the equation for an ortogonal plane that contains the line $\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+3}{3}=\frac{z-2}{-1}$. Assume (ON-system).

So my plan was the following, why not just project a plane on the normal-vector of the given plane $tN:t(1,1,-2)$?

We have that the plane we are to determine contains the line $\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+3}{3}=\frac{z-2}{-1} \iff L:(1,-3,2)+t(2,3,-1)$. 
Given this we should be able to project a point on the line on the plane. We set $t=0$ and choose $P_0:(1,-3,2)$.

$P_0-tN=(1,-3,2)-t(1,1-2)=(1-t,-3-t,2-2t)$

If I now put $(1-t,-3-t,2-2t)$ into the equation of the plane I get $-6t=0 \iff t=0$. So this must mean that the point in on the given plane.

So what I'm I doing wrong, and what should I be doing instead? A bit of guidance would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: The dot-product of the normal vectors must be zero!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plane which contains the given line must contain the points $P_1=(1,-3,2)$ and $P_2=(3,0,1)$ therefore its normal vector must be othogonal to $P_2-P_1=(2,3,-1)$ that is for $n=(a,b,c)$

- $2a+3b-c=0$

moreover its normal vector must be othogonal to the normal vector of the given plane, that is

- $a+b-2c=0$

then we can determine a normal and then the plane equation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the problem! So let $t\tilde{N}$ be the normal of of the unknown plane and $v=P_1-P_2=(2,3,-1)$. We want $t\tilde{N}\cdot(2,3,-1)=0$ so that those are orthogonal, right? Thereafter we want  $tN\cdot t\tilde{N}=0$ so that the two normals are orthogonal. I'm I on the right here?

Comment: @MisterButter Yes exactly.